# Checkout from the svn and now getting the error RCSClient.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed

Tags: ios, xcode, smartsvn

The company is using SmartSVN, for the repository. I checked out the code and now I am getting this error. I tried again with no luck. Again I am getting the same error. Closed the Xcode and reopened it , again the same issues. I have doing the same old process (check out) for over a month with no issues, but now I am facing the issue. [image]Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right click on rcsclient.xcodeproj file and choose "show package contents", then open file project.pbxproj (use text editer or something else). Fix all conflict in this file.

Comment: I did as you said. I am seeing a lot of text. I opened .pbxproj in text editor. Now what next, any hints?

Comment: I got it running, I found out for <<<<<<< .mine and just deleted, and it started working again. YEAH!!!

Comment: It also should have worked to revert your local changes using svn.

Comment: @KumarUtsav Because you got conflict with your own version and new version you pull from server. So you can not open this project.